# Syncing local wordpress installation with live site using gulp watch and browser-sync?

Tags: wordpress, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

I'm making a WordPress website on my local environment using gulp watch and browser-sync. How would I go about being able to have this local environment setup sync with a live website so that file changes and sass compiles that are being made in development are automatically deployed to the live site? Also I would need some method of syncing database tables.

Cheers

Comment: Usually you seperate the development stage and the live stage. If you really want to develop live I recommend installing node on your server (not the best solution). Otherwise you can use programs like codeship to update your commits to your live enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against auto-syncing your environment. When you break something locally you immediately break it on the production server too.

Now to answer your question, use a program like FTPBox [Download from their website](http://ftpbox.org)

For database syncing you would have to write a import/export script on the server and your local environment and use something like [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to put your database in a .sql file. (assuming you are using either MySQL or MariaDB)

Again, I strongly recommend against doing this and just deploying when you have everything stable.

Answer (score 0):

I echo the statements above about separating your development tasks from deployment.  You can set up a separate gulp task that you run only after you are sure you want to upload your files.

If you want to deploy using a gulp task, try [vinyl-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp).  From their documentation:

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

gulp.task( 'deploy', function () {

    var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'mywebsite.tld',
        user:     'me',
        password: 'mypass',
        parallel: 10,
        log:      gutil.log
    } );

    var globs = [
        'src/**',
        'css/**',
        'js/**',
        'fonts/**',
        'index.html'
    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance

    return gulp.src( globs, { base: '.', buffer: false } )
        .pipe( conn.newer( '/public_html' ) ) // only upload newer files
        .pipe( conn.dest( '/public_html' ) );

} );
```

And be sure to look at [setting up your ftp credentials safely in gulp](https://blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-sync-local-and-server-development-gulp) before you do anything.  It is a very good article.  And .gitignore any credential file!

Comment: Cheers appreciate it!